# How to customize login form design?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-login

I want to customize and create my own design on my login form but i don't know how to call the login form i use the form inside the admin. How can i remove the username: & password: and put it inside the text box ?

i don't know how to start.

Login.html

```
<div class="container">
   <form method="post">
      {% block content %}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" name="button">Login</button>
      {% endblock %}
   </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my output

Username: {text box}
Password: {text box}
login button

what i want is

{text box "Username" "username_icon"}
{text box "Password" "password_icon"}
button login

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom html for `username` and `password` field

```
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="username"></label>
        <!-- your icon -->
        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" required="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <label for="password"></label>
        <!-- your icon -->
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="">
```

Comment: i'm gonna remove my {{ form.as_p }} ?

Comment: Yes. You need to remove `{{ form.as_p }}`

Comment: here's my urls.py path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login/Login.html'), name="login"),

Comment: is that the path that i connect to the username and password that i create in my admin ?

Comment: @shafik how the user can login if it doesnt use a request.POST form??